# Verify the number of times a protected method is called using Moq

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, moq

In my unit-tests I'm mocking a protected method using Moq, and would like to assert that it is called a certain number of times. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390632/verifying-protected-abstract-methods-are-called-using-moq) describes something similar for an earlier version of Moq:

```
//expect that ChildMethod1() will be called once. (it's protected)
testBaseMock.Protected().Expect("ChildMethod1")
  .AtMostOnce()
  .Verifiable();

...
testBase.Verify();
```

but this no longer works; the syntax has changed since then and I cannot find the new equivalent using Moq 4.x:

```
testBaseMock.Protected().Setup("ChildMethod1")
  // no AtMostOnce() or related method anymore
  .Verifiable();

...
testBase.Verify();
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the [Moq.Protected](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq.Testeroids/Moq/Moq.Protected) namespace, there is an [IProtectedMock](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq.Testeroids/Moq/IProtectedMock%28TMock%29) interface that has a Verify method taking Times as a parameter.

**Edit**
This is available since at least Moq 4.0.10827. Syntax example:

```
testBaseMock.Protected().Setup("ChildMethod1");

...
testBaseMock.Protected().Verify("ChildMethod1", Times.Once());
```

Answer (score 31):

To augment Ogata's answer, we can also **verify a protected method that takes arguments**:

```
testBaseMock.Protected().Setup(
    "ChildMethod1",
    ItExpr.IsAny<string>(),
    ItExpr.IsAny<string>());

testBaseMock.Protected().Verify(
    "ChildMethod1", 
    Times.Once(),
    ItExpr.IsAny<string>()
    ItExpr.IsAny<string>());
```

For instance, that would verify `ChildMethod1(string x, string y)`.

See also: http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq.Testeroids/Moq/IProtectedMock(TMock)/M/Verify

Comment: Is there any way to verify that protected async was called with some parameters? I've tried to use ...Protected().Verify(...), but looks like it does not work with async methods.

Comment: @Rroman what issue do you have with protected async methods?
I've just had to verify `HttpRequestMessage.SendAsync` and what I experienced was that if I used `Moq.It.Is<>`, it threw with a message "Use ItExpr.IsNull<TValue> rather than a null argument value, as it prevents proper method lookup". 
When I changed to `Moq.Protected.ItExpr.Is<>` then it worked fine

Comment: If the arguments to the protected method are an Interface or Enum, should this still work?? I'm getting this when i try with anything other than simple types:
`System.ArgumentException: Use ItExpr.IsNull<TValue> rather than a null argument value, as it prevents proper method lookup`