# Verifying methods called with Moq

Tags: c#, moq

Trying to verify a method is being called within a mock but cna't seem to figure out why I keep getting an exception thrown that it isn't being called. The method in question is as follows:

```
public class CustomerSyncEngine {
public CustomerSyncEngine(ILoggingProvider loggingProvider, ICrmProvider crmProvider, ICacheProvider cacheProvider) {
  Logger = loggingProvider;
  CrmProvider = crmProvider;
  CacheProvider = cacheProvider;
}
public virtual void SyncPickLists() {
  Logger.LogBeginPicklistSync();

  // get all the pick lists from the local cache
  var localCachePickLists = CacheProvider.GetPickLists().ToList();
  // get all the pick lists from the remote system
  var crmPickLists = CrmProvider.GetPickLists().ToList();

  // build a sync plan
  var changes = BuildPickListUpdatePlan(localCachePickLists, crmPickLists).ToList();

  // run the sync
  RunPickListSync(changes);

  Logger.LogEndPicklistSync();
}
}
```

I've then written a test like so:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestSyncPickLists() {
  // arrange
  var mockCrm = new Mock<ICrmProvider>();
  mockCrm.Verify(x => x.GetPickLists(), Times.Once(), "ICrmProvider.GetPickLists not called");

  var mockCache = Mock.Of<ICacheProvider>();
  var mockLogger = Mock.Of<ILoggingProvider>();

  // act
  var syncEngine = new CustomerSyncEngine(mockLogger, mockCrm.Object, mockCache);
  syncEngine.SyncPickLists();

  // assert
  mockCrm.VerifyAll();
}
```

When I run it the test fails with the message I specified in the Verify(). So I set a bunch of breakpoints and I see that the test never calls the syncEngine.SyncPickLists() method which is confusing to me. So I comment out the two Verify() & VerifyAll() statements and now I see things being called correctly. What am I missing here? It looks like I'm doing exactly what is shown in the [Quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart) as well as on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728873/verify-the-number-of-times-a-protected-method-is-called-using-moq).

Comment: You call `Verify` after the call to `SyncPickLists` - it's not a deferred thing, as it checks the value then and there. Move the line below your call to `SyncPickLists` and you should pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer posted by Tejs in comment to original post.

You call Verify after the call to SyncPickLists - it's not a deferred thing, as it checks the value then and there. Move the line below your call to SyncPickLists and you should pass. – Tejs